Managing MySQL Change Deployment in AWS RDS
I am trying to setup a test database and a live database using seperate MySQL instances running on Amazon RDS.
This would theoretically keep live and test data seperate, and allow changes to be made to the test database configuration that could later be applied to the live database configuration.
I have previously written a MySQL script for changing database tables, although I am unsure whether this is the best way to do an update, since it requires manual creation and execution of scripts.
Is there a better way to manage the deployment of database changes in MySQL using RDS?
There exists the snapshot and restore snapshot features, although I am not planning to migrate data, so it would be a configuration only migration.

Unless you use some kind of an ORM, you need to manually write your DDL scripts. However, their execution does not necessarily have to be manual, those can be part of your devops pipeline. You may want to consider using liquibase (or something equivalent) that can manage your database changes.

There are numerous schema change management systems for MySQL. Some are integrated with ORM frameworks and some are standalone. But recommending tools is discouraged by Stack Overflow's policies.
